# AWS S3 Image URL Showing Crack Image

Tags: express, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am new to AWS and serverless framework. My problem is that same code (written in express js without using any logic of serverless and for this code there is a separate **Elastic Beanstalk** backend) is able to upload image to AWS S3 and resulting Image url is showing Image in browser.

However, the same code configured with serverless framework (there is **Lambda function** for this) is also able to upload image to AWS S3 (for both case bucket is same) but this time the resulting image url is only showing crack image (I mean whenever image cannot open, default image something like that).

In both cases I am getting an image url after uploading to s3 and that url with other text data. I am storing in my Amazon RDS MySQL database.

**My serverless.Yaml file**

```
service: serverlessbackend
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: ap-south-1
  timeout: 10
  environment:
    DB_HOST: "something.rds.amazonaws.com"
    DB_USER: "user"
    DB_PASSWORD: "something"
    DB_NAME: "something"
    AWS_ACCESSKEY: "something"
    AWS_SECRETKEY: "something"
    MY_AWS_REGION: "ap-south-1"


functions:
  myLambdaFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: "ANY {proxy+}"

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

**index.js file**

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql2");
app.use(express.json());
let pool = require("./db/index");

let categoryRoutes = require("./routes/categoryRoutes");


app.use("/category", categoryRoutes);


module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

**categoryroutes.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const { pool } = require("../db");
const { deleteFromAws, uploadToAws } = require("../utils/aws");
const multer = require("multer");
const { uniqueString } = require("../utils/unique");

const router = express.Router();


const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});


router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.file);
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
  }

  try {
  
    let result = await uploadToAws(req.file);
  
    let { Location: imgUrl, Key } = result;

    console.log(result);
  

    if (imgUrl && Key) {
      const query = "INSERT INTO temp SET ?";

      const data = {
        category: req.body.category,
        category_id: uniqueString(),
        image_path: imgUrl,
        image_name: Key,
      };
      // The "?" in the query is a placeholder for the data object

      pool.query(query, data, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
        }
        // console.log(result);
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "File uploaded successfully" });
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error("something wrong");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.send(err.message);
  }
});
```

**Here is upload to AWS file:**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { generateUniqueImageName } = require("./unique");

// Configure AWS credentials
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESSKEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRETKEY,
  region: process.env.MY_AWS_REGION, // e.g., 'us-east-1'
});

// Create a new instance of the S3 service

const uploadToAws = async (file) => {
  // console.log(file);
  
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  const params = {
    Bucket: "something",
    Key: `uploads/IMG-${generateUniqueImageName(file.originalname)}`, // The file name to be used in the S3 bucket
    ContentType: file.mimetype,
    Body: file.buffer, // The file content as a buffer
  };

  return await s3.upload(params).promise();
};
```

With serverless framework image url looks like this:

[image: with serverless framework image url looks like this]

Without serverless, image url is showing image:

[image: without serverless, image url is showing image]

I have checked my access key and secret key, all fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works locally when you run it and when running it in lambda it no longer works that tells us that the problem is what you are sending to the lambda function.

There are a number of issues with code, the first of which is

```js
// Configure AWS credentials
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESSKEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRETKEY,
  region: process.env.MY_AWS_REGION, // e.g., 'us-east-1'
});
```

AccessKeyId and secretAccessKey should NEVER EVER be set in a lambda function. They are never necessary because Lambda already has its own credentials, [More details on when to use credentials](https://dev.to/authress/when-to-use-aws-credentials-2ki4).

Future it should be clear that there is a problem on this line:

```js
  console.log(req.file);
```

Are you actually getting back out the file contents? According to your code you later do this

```js
Body: file.buffer, // The file content as a buffer
```

Which means that req.file has a buffer in it. This does not look remotely like it should when sending binary data to a lambda function. You should expect the data coming into the lambda to be base64 encoded and require explicit decoding. Instead of writing this to S3, it would make more sense to  echo back to the caller the file.buffer and then you can write that to your local disk. After writing it you can validate that it is indeed correct.

After that mirror echo works, you can review the `console.log(req.file)` to see the actual contents.

---

Lastly on a meta-level, to get better answers I recommend deleting everything from the post which is not absolutely necessary. For instance, the post only needs:

- Code that does not work

It does not need:

- Your whole lambda function
- The working and broken pictures
- Explanation of other factors or where else it works

Focus on only the parts that matter. I suggest starting with writing the minimal code you can to prove it works locally. Can you do it in one line of code? two lines of code?